# Laravel 5.1 - Session id keeps changing

Tags: php, laravel, session

I tried to use session in an event handler in Laravel 5.1, but when I `dd($this->session);` I found that session id kept changing each time I refresh page in browser.

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Session\Store;

class ViewHandler
{

    public function handle()
    {
        dd($this->session);
    }
}
```

This is what it outputs:

```
Store {#229 ▼
  #id: "c46361f5550d0061eb9f579672d3d04b0d54b5be"
  #name: "laravel_session"
  #attributes: []
  #bags: []
  #metaBag: MetadataBag {#230 ▶}
  #bagData: []
  #handler: FileSessionHandler {#228 ▶}
  #started: false
}
```

The id will keep changing. Also, storage\framework\sessions is empty, and I am sure this folder is writable.

I didn't change anything in config\session.php . `lifetime` in session.php is 120. How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Neither the `Store` class has any `session` attr nor the class you have declared has any attr with the name `session`? So what you actually are printing?

Comment: Check config/session.php

Comment: I changed to use Session, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: check permission of session store folder

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: The version of PHP is 5.6.10

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the important parts of your session config (config/session.php)